# Javascript use of Object.create and properties pointers not being dereferenced from prototype

Tags: javascript, object, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

Can anybody explain what's going on bellow when I `o1.set('bar');`? I'm wondering why `o2.name` is also set at this time and the same doesn't happen when I `o2.set('fox');`, I mean, `o1.name` remains `bar`.

Why o1.name and o2.name point to same object even though I'd changed the old value (`foo`) but the same doesn't happen when I change o2.name?

```js
var Person = {
 name: "foo",
 get: function get() {
  return this.name;
 },
 set: function set(sur) {
  this.name = sur;
 }
},
o1 = Person,
o2 = Object.create(o1);

// true "foo" "foo"
console.log(o1.name === o2.name, o1.get(), o2.get()); 

o1.set('bar');

// true "bar" "bar"
console.log(o1.name === o2.name, o1.get(), o2.get());

o2.set('fox');

// false "bar" "fox"
console.log(o1.name === o2.name, o1.get(), o2.get());
```

Another behavior can be seen bellow. The difference here is that I extend Person prototype even for `o1` object.

```js
 var Person = {
  name: "foo",
  get: function get() {
   return this.name;
  },
  set: function set(sur) {
   this.name = sur;
  }
 },
 o1 = Object.create(Person),
 o2 = Object.create(Person);

 // true "foo" "foo"
 console.log(o1.name === o2.name, o1.get(), o2.get()); 

 o1.set('bar');

 // false "bar" "foo"
 console.log(o1.name === o2.name, o1.get(), o2.get());

 o2.set('fox');

 // false "bar" "fox"
 console.log(o1.name === o2.name, o1.get(), o2.get());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be found at the good "**Programming JavaScript Applications**" book by **Eric Elliot** and I think this concern can be found here [Delegate Prototypes](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000000262/ch03.html#delegate-prototype).

Eric says that:

"*In JavaScript, objects have an internal reference to a delegate prototype. When an object is queried for a property or method, the JavaScript engine first checks the object. If the key doesn't exist on that object, it checks the delegate prototype, and so on up the prototype chain. The prototype chain typically ends at the Object prototype.*"

and completes the explannation with:

"*Properties on the prototype act like defaults. When you set them on the instance, the instance value overrides the value for that instance, only.*"

In other words, I understood that when call `o1.get()` I'm changing the prototype and `o2` object is extending it. However when I call `o2.get()` I'm not changing the prototype anymore but the `o2` instance. That's why after that any change on `o1.name` is now detached from `o2.name`.

Answer (score 4):

The object `o2` *inherits* the "name" property from its prototype chain. However, as soon as the property is set, it's the object itself that's affected.

To put it another way, the prototype chain is not consulted when an object property is being set. The property updated (or added) is always on the target object directly. The prototype chain is only consulted when property values are being examined.

This in the call `o2.set("fox");` the `set()` function is itself found on the prototype. However, the value of `this` in that call is `o2`, not `o1`, so the assignment to `this.name` affects `o2` directly.

Comment: very good @Pointy could you please add some links about this topic that explains in deep?

Comment: @thiagoh I don't know of any specific reference for this behavior; it's just how the language works.